# JSF 2 : Why my first bean is called during an ajax action to a second bean?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have two backbeans, one to retrieve datas in a ui:repeat and one to perform an action.

When my page is rendered, if I perform an action with the second backbean, the first is called (initialized) even if I use an ajax action with Richfaces 4. It is not the case if I don't use a repeat component.
It's annoying that the first bean is called with a repeat element.

Here my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat var="currentValue" value="#{test_form_backBean_1.testSimpleModels}">
            #{currentValue.name}
            <br />
        </ui:repeat>

        <a4j:commandButton value="Tester" actionListener="#{test_form_backBean_2.test}" execute="@this" render="@this">

        </a4j:commandButton>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

My first bean :

```
@Named("test_form_backBean_1")
@RequestScoped
public class Test_form_backBean_1 {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test_form_backBean_1.class);

    private List<Test_Simple_Model> testSimpleModels;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
            logger.trace("Initialisation de Test_form_backBean_1.");

            testSimpleModels = new ArrayList<Test_Simple_Model>();
            testSimpleModels.add(new Test_Simple_Model(1L, "name_1"));
            testSimpleModels.add(new Test_Simple_Model(2L, "name_2"));
            testSimpleModels.add(new Test_Simple_Model(3L, "name_3"));
            testSimpleModels.add(new Test_Simple_Model(4L, "name_4"));
    }

    public List<Test_Simple_Model> getTestSimpleModels() {
        logger.trace("getTestSimpleModels() : appel.");
        return testSimpleModels;
    }

    public void setTestSimpleModels(List<Test_Simple_Model> testSimpleModels) {
        logger.trace("setTestSimpleModels() : appel.");
        this.testSimpleModels = testSimpleModels;
    }

}
```

The second :

```
@Named("test_form_backBean_2")
@RequestScoped
public class Test_form_backBean_2 {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test_form_backBean_2.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        logger.trace("Initialisation de Test_form_backBean_2.");

    }

    public void test() {
        logger.trace("test() : appel de la fonction de test.");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your beans are request scoped, meaning they go out of scope as soon as a request-response lifecycle has completed, be that the result of a non-faces request (full page) or an AJAX post-back request.

You need to use view scoped beans instead. Since you are using CDI, you could either stop using that and switch to using JSF 2 managed beans which has a `@ViewScoped` annotation, or you could continue to use CDI with Seam Faces 3 which apparently also supports `@ViewScoped`. (I don't know by what magic it does that, but apparently it just works.)

Please also try to use generally accepted naming conventions for Java such as `TestFormBackBean1` instead of `Test_form_backBean_1`.

Comment: First, thanks you for your answer. Yes, viewscoped changes this behaviour but I don't know why the first bean is called if I use a repeat element. Because without this element (using by example just this    #{test_form_backBean_1.testSimpleModels.get(0).name}), my first bean is not called even with a request scoped.

Comment: Interesting. What if you use `render="@none"`? Also, what version of RichFaces are you using?

Comment: RF-4.0.0.Final. I used execute="@this" and render="@this", if I change to render="@none", it's the same thing.

Comment: It would appear to be the same thing superficially, but under the hood it just wouldn't trigger any rendering at all. I have a suspicion that the `ui:repeat` is getting processed for post-back responses because it's part of facelets. Please humour me and just try it. :)

Comment: With viewscoped (from Seam 3 Faces), there is always a call to getTestSimpleModels().. It's the similar issue with h:dataTable, rich:dataTable and certainly with all others components which iterate on a list.

Comment: OK, so you didn't try `render="@none"`?